# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 while installing requirements

Tags: python, android

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ib3vl4vt/web.py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ib3vl4vt/web.py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ib3vl4vt/web.py/
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-ib3vl4vt/web.py/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from web import __version__
  File "/tmp/pip-install-ib3vl4vt/web.py/web/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

While installing requirements.txt in InsecureBankv2/AndroLabServer, I got this errors.
Because of these problems, It seems like InsecureBankv2 app won't login to my server.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
pip install utils
```

Comment: @MMascarin Maybe try pip install python-utils and import python-utils as utils

Answer (score 0):

How i got around this error message was do py -3 -m pip install  and it worked properly. I'm using Windows 10 as of July 2020 and inside of a virtual environment.

The error was happening when i attempted to install coderedcms.

Answer (score 0):

try this for linux

```
python3 -m pip install win32gui
```